# drupal | migrating changes to production

Tags: mysql, drupal, drupal-6, migration

I have a Drupal site running in production. After some time I had changes in code and through admin as well, some configurations, changed content types and changed body of some pages etc. Meanwhile the production database was growing. Now I want my changes in production by not loosing the data which is already in production DB. One way is to repeat the same steps as of Dev on production. That looks not good to me. Is there any automated procedure to migrate the changes?

Thanks

Comment: The files you should be able to update just like that. When it comes to configuration, you should look into Features. As an alternative you could make your own module, which set these configuration changes you have made.

Answer (score 1):

The modules [features](http://drupal.org/project/features) and [strongarm](http://drupal.org/project/strongarm) will do the trick for you.

Features can help you save and migrate the content types, for example, while strongarm will help you migrate site settings and configuration information that is stored in variables.

After installing the two modules, go to Admin --> Structure --> Features --> Manage on your dev site and create features for the changes you want to transfer from dev to production.  If you have both features and strongarm installed, it will let you create features that capture both site building components (content types, views you created, roles and permissions you have changed, etc) and site settings (settings stored in variables -- you'll see the long list of settings you can export once you install the strongarm module).  When you create your feature, it is exported as code (as a module), and you can then add that module to any additional sites in which you want to add the components you selected when creating your feature(s).

You will have to install the two modules on your production environment too.  Then add the features you just created in your dev environment to your production site.  Once set up though, you can transfer changes between dev and production environments more easily going forward!

Here is the features documentation: http://drupal.org/node/580026.

Hope this doesn't sound too confusing!